AWS DynamoDB Interface VPC Endpoint (PrivateLink) cannot enable Private DNS
Tried to enable Private DNS of a DynamoDB Interface VPC Endpoint (PrivateLink) but it says Private DNS can't be enabled because the service com.amazonaws.ap-southeast-2.dynamodb does not provide a private DNS name.

Please explain why.
The document says both Gateway and Interface VPC endpoints can co-exist in a VPC. Hence, existing Gateway VPC should not be an issue.

You can create interface endpoints and retain the existing gateway endpoint in the same Amazon VPC

